# How to say when waiters are busy in a restaurant

Tags: word-choice

I was at the restaurant with some friends, waiting for someone taking our order but unfortunately it took so long.

Then I was about to comment the situation, but I realized that I don't really know how to formulate it properly.

- The waiters are so busy tonight.(I don't like this tense because I want to use something stronger than just "busy"
- The waiters are drown tonight
- The waiters are so overwhelmed

Which one is the best?
thanks

Comment: If the problem was that there were too many customers for the waiters to attend to, then "The waiters are so overwhelmed." is best. Using *drown* is abstract, so you would need to rephrase a bit. "The waiters are *drowning with customers* tonight."

Comment: _The waiters are **being slammed**._

Answer (score 2):

Some options:

- They are overwhelmed with work tonight.
- They are overburdened with work tonight.
- They have tons to do tonight.
- They are up to their ears in work tonight.
- They are drowning in work tonight.
- They are snowed under with work tonight.
- They are as busy as bees tonight.